# File could not be opened because it is empty

Tags: python, flask

I want to upload 2 images from requests. I am creating the function which accepts the `request.files` as a parameter and save both images.

The function is :

```
def store_offer_images(files, **service_response):
    """
    Stores the Images
    """
    create_diretory_if_not_exist()
    lrg_img, sml_img = files.get('detail_image'), files.get('listing_image')

    lrg_img_filename = service_response.get('content').get('offerId') + ".png"
    sml_img_filename = service_response.get('content').get('offerId') + ".png"

    sml_img.save(
        os.path.join(config.NORMAL_FILE_UPLOAD_FOLDER, sml_img_filename))
    lrg_img.save(
        os.path.join(config.LARGE_FILE_UPLOAD_FOLDER, lrg_img_filename))
```

When I am trying to save the images. It saves properly. `files` is the `request.files` and `service_response` is the `kwargs`.

When I want to open image in Finder(OS GUI Window), then I got the message:

`The file “b516f2dca72e4f559c3a72a1f48727a9.png” could not be opened because it is empty.`

[image]

How can I upload the images?

**Edit:**
When I look files in the pdb, here are the response:

```
(pdb) files.get('detail_image')
(pdb) <FileStorage: u'python-640x444.png' ('image/png')>
```

The model which models my request data is:

```
import datetime
from app_config import AppConfig


class Offer(object):
    """
    Offer Details
    """

    def __init__(self, form):
        self.REST_API_TIME_FORMAT = AppConfig().REST_API_TIME_FORMAT
        self.title = form.get('title')
        self.start_date = form.get('startsOn') + ' 00:00'
        self.end_date = form.get('endsOn') + ' 23:59'
        self.short_description = form.get('shortDescription')
        self.long_description = form.get('longDescription')
        self.outlets = form.getlist('outlets')
        self.offer_value = form.get('offerValue')
        self.offer_old_value = form.get('oldValue')
        self.currency = form.get('currency')

    def add_offer_body(self):
        """
        Return the request body in json format
        """
        outlets_list = []
        for i in self.outlets:
            outlets_list.append({'code': i})

        starts_on_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            self.start_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        ends_on_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            self.end_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

        body = {
            "outlets": outlets_list,
            "title": self.title,
            "shortDescription": self.short_description,
            "longDescription": self.long_description,
            "endsOn": ends_on_date.strftime(self.REST_API_TIME_FORMAT),
            "startsOn": starts_on_date.strftime(self.REST_API_TIME_FORMAT),
            "isActive": "true",
        }

        if self.offer_value is not u'':
            body['offerValue'] = {
                "value": self.offer_value,
                "currency": self.currency
            }

        if self.offer_old_value is not u'':
            body["offerOldValue"] = {
                "value": self.offer_old_value,
                "currency": self.currency
            }
        return body

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title
```

The `views.py` is:

```
@portal.route('/admin/offers/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_offer():
    """
    Return status of added offer
    """
    offer = Offer(request.form)
    if controller.valid_content(request.files):
        service_response = controller.add_offer(offer)
        if 'errors' in service_response:
            message = str(service_response.get('errors')[0].get('message'))
            flash("Adding Offer Failed.!! " + message)
            current_app.logger.error(
                'Offer adding failed with details' + str(request.form))
            return redirect(url_for('portal.list_running_offers'))
        else:
            controller.store_offer_images(request.files, **service_response)
            current_app.logger.info('User added a offer successfully.')
            flash("Offer added successfully..!!")
            return redirect(url_for('portal.list_running_offers'))
    else:
        flash("Please upload all Images of mentioned Resolution.!!")
        return render_template(
            'addoffer.jinja', body=offer.add_offer_body(), help=help_messages)
```

The HTML is:

```
{% extends "base.jinja" %}

{% block script %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/addOffer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
     <link href="static/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


{% endblock %}


{% block title %}
    Add Offer
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <legend><h1>
        Add Offer
    </h1></legend>
    <br>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <form id="offerForm"enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url_for('portal.add_offer') }}" data-toggle="validator" role="form" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="file">OFFER LISTING IMAGE *</label>
                <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
                    <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control" name="listing_image" accept="image/x-png" data-error="{{help.listing_image}}" required>
                    <span class="help-block with-errors">{{help.listing_image}}</span>

                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="file">OFFER DETAIL IMAGE *</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
                        <input id="image" type="file" class="form-control" name="detail_image" accept="image/x-png" 
                        data-error="{{help.detail_image}}" required>
                        <span class="help-block with-errors">{{help.detail_image}}</span>

                    </div>
                </div>

</form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div></div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How do you try to open the image?

Comment: @Jeremad From Finder

Comment: It looks like you're creating a file but writing anything in it.

Comment: `<form>` tag is there. It is just a small part of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was happening because If I perform any operation on Image, it will move my pointer at last, so when you save the image, it start saving image where your pointer is, which is at the last. So the saved image is empty.

Now to fixed this I just move my pointers to the beginning. Here is sample code what I did:

```
if img is not None and img.filename != u'':
            img.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            size = img.tell()
            imgs = Image.open(img)
            res = imgs.size
            img.seek(0)
```